# How does Sybase handle time zones?

Tags: jdbc, timezone, sybase, sap-ase

I need to understand how Sybase handles and stores time zones:

For example, if a JDBC client is for example in timezone +1:00 and the Sybase DB is in timezone +2:00:

1. When the JDBC client application write to the database (e.g. INSERT/UPDATE), will Sybase convert the datetime received from the client application to its local timezone when it stores it in the db table?
2. When the JDBC client application reads from the database, will the Sybase resultset contain the client or the server's timezone with SELECT queries?
3. If the DB server box is later moved to another country which is for example in timezone +3:00, will the datetime values stored in the Sybase database become inconsistent with datetime inserted after the move?

So with the above in mind, when do I need to convert date/times and should I convert it to the server or the client's time zone?

Comment: Experiment and you shall discover the answers for yourself.  Or read the documentation.  You will probably find that the behavior varies by data type.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have a free Sybase database server that I can experiment on.  I am also not a DBA, that is why I am asking the question.

Answer (score 2):

Sybase ASE will store whatever time stamp is passed to it by the client application.  It assumes that the application knows what it's doing, and will not do any conversion.

This means that the data written and the data read will be based on the client application's time zone, not the database server's time zone.

This also means that you can move the database server where ever you like, without causing inconsistency in the data, since you are using the time set by the application.

Comment: I'll add to the above though where the client application reads the data from the Sybase server using itssystem date (getdate()) this will be based on the database host local timezone setting not the client application timezone. You can use getutcdate() to obtain consistent timing across timezones as this will always return the UTC date.

If in doubt check

Comment: Would be nice to have some Sybase documentation to confirm your statements.

Comment: @DiegoVictordeJesus There isn't specific documentation, because this is more of a design decision on whether to have the time defined by the application/client or by the database/server.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that Sysbase stores the microseconds from 00:00 1 Jan 1970.

- **SELECT\READ:** returns the converted date (that was stored in microseconds) in the timezone of the host machine.
- **INSERT\WRITE:** inserts the microseconds value based on the timezone of the host machine timezone.

If you move the database and change host timezone, dates returned to the application will change (wich suck), at least the string representation of the date.

My recommendation, have DB and Application always handle in UTC, make the conversion in the presentation layer.